# Importing a package into every module automatically or creating a global variable with Webpack

Tags: webpack, global-variables, lodash

I'd like to make lodash available in every module without having to keep importing it. How would I do this with Webpack? I tried using `webpack.ProvidePlugin` as [described here](https://medium.com/@peterpme/implicit-imports-in-webpack-using-provideplugin-can-make-your-life-easier-7d33a288675d#.kq853czb0), but I still receive the error `_ is undefined`:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        _ : 'lodash'
    })
]
```

I don't want to simply go the `window._ = require('lodash')` route, because then I still have to use `window._` every time I wish to user the library.

Comment: Can you paste the call to `ProvidePlugin` that you have added?

Comment: @PavithraKodmad updated